Find a table with custom unique id in a google doc with googleapis nodejs package
For a project I am working on, we are using Google Docs as a tool for a review process.
Somebody creates a document in our platform using a Rich text editor and then for the review process, since implementing inline commenting or diff visualization requires a lot of work on our end, it has been decided to use Google Docs as a proxy where commenting, updating and keeping change history is already implemented there.
The Google Doc is created when the review request is sent. We convert the content we have in the database into the Google Doc and get a link without issue.
The Google Doc content is initially generated with the signature of the person who sent the review request at the end. No issue adding an image and the signature text at the end of the document (the signature is an image of the drawing and the signature text like an email signature with rich text).
The issue is adding the signature of the person who reviewed at the end of the process.
The requirement is that both signature must be next to each others.
Obviously, I thought about using a table to structure this like following:



Signature image from John
Signature Image from Jacob




John LockeManagerBox & Co
Jacob



It works, but eventually, the signature can be updated later and this is when the problem starts.
I don't find any easy way to find that table to update it's content.
Removing it and regenerating the table with the content is also find. The problem is how to find it.
I don't see in the doc any way to create a table programmatically with a custom id that I can use later to find this table using
const docs = google.docs({ version: "v1", auth });
const documentContent = await docs.documents.get({
    documentId,
  });

// how to find the table in documentResult.data.body.content without a custom id ...?


I have to apologize for my poor English skills. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect in order for me to understand your question correctly? First, I would like to understand your question correctly.
